# How to replace string with bash script and write back the Result

Tags: linux, bash, csv

There is a CSV file with some columns, the first column is a 5 digit customer number, the other columns are separated with ";"

Here is a example:

```
12345;some;other;cols;comes;here
;some;other;cols;comes;here
;some;other;cols;comes;here
67890;some;other;cols;comes;here
34567;some;other;cols;comes;here
;some;other;cols;comes;here
;some;other;cols;comes;here
;some;other;cols;comes;here
;some;other;cols;comes;here
24315;some;other;cols;comes;here
```

If the first column is empty than I need to set the last given customer ID. The result should look like:

```
12345;some;other;cols;comes;here
12345;some;other;cols;comes;here
12345;some;other;cols;comes;here
67890;some;other;cols;comes;here
34567;some;other;cols;comes;here
34567;some;other;cols;comes;here
34567;some;other;cols;comes;here
34567;some;other;cols;comes;here
34567;some;other;cols;comes;here
24315;some;other;cols;comes;here
```

Now I read the file linewise with bash script, and want to check if the line starts with a number. If yes than explode the line by ";" and set customerID with array[0] (the first value). Next I check if the line not began with a number and want to write the five digits on the begin of the line. But I can't access the Array Index with the customer ID.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    row=$line
    if echo $row |grep "^[0-9].*$" > /dev/null;
      then
        arr=$(echo $row | tr ";" "\n")
        echo ${arr[0]};
    fi
done < $1
```

I get the whole line without ";" and not the CustomerID as arr[0] next I don't know how to write the digits at begin of the line back to the file. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -v id=12345 -F ';' '$1==""{$1=id;} {id=$1; print}'  OFS=';' file
```

- awk uses field separator `;` which makes you access each individual field as `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc.
- `-v id=12345` is a command line argument that you pass to awk to be used when first field is empty
- `$1=""` is a condition that checks whether first field is empty
- `$1=id` is setting `$1` to passed variable `id`
- `{id=$1; print}` sets the `id` variable to be used for next line and then prints the line

**OUTPUT:**

```
12345;some;other;cols;comes;here
12345;some;other;cols;comes;here
12345;some;other;cols;comes;here
67890;some;other;cols;comes;here
34567;some;other;cols;comes;here
34567;some;other;cols;comes;here
34567;some;other;cols;comes;here
34567;some;other;cols;comes;here
34567;some;other;cols;comes;here
24315;some;other;cols;comes;here
```

Comment: I add a example into the question. Can you explain the awk Command that I can implement it into the script?

Comment: Thx for your help, but the ID is not fixed. The empty string should be replaced with the last given ID.

Comment: Yes i know, awk command is NOT making it fixed, it is always overwriting id with previous row's `customer id` by using `id=$1;`. I am passing id for the case when first rows have empty first column.

Comment: Okay than I misunderstood the command, okay but in all corrected line the is no ";"

Answer (score 1):

A pure bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Globally set IFS, if you don't like it, wrap it all in a subshell.
IFS=';'
lastID=-1
while read -a row; do
    [[ -z ${row[0]} ]] && row[0]=$lastID
    lastID=${row[0]}
    # Abusing IFS
    echo "${row[*]}"
done < "$1"
```